# SVN update and commit problem used with git-svn

Tags: svn, git, version-control, git-svn

I can't svn up or commit. :(

There is a svn centrally and I use git locally using git-svn.

Basically, somehow, I added a folder that had .svn folders into the git and committed it to svn. Both git and central svn happily committed the .svn as the content folder, without complaining.

Now, I can't svn up to the existing folder as, once a folder is created, .svn is automatically added and it complains, "there is an unversioned .svn within the folder". For the same reason I cannot even clone the svn repo again. (The clone stops at that particular point, infinitely.)

I can't svn commit because the working copy within .svn (content folder) doesn't exist.

Because `git-svn` was able to put the .svn inside the svn, it should be able to remove it, I thought. I earlier renamed this folder and committed, so now the git thinks there is no such folder, whereas the svn shows 2 folders one of them with the old .svn folders. So, git cannot exactly delete this folder either.

What is the way to remove the .svn out of the central svn repo.

I tried to reverse merge the commit that introduced .svn within the svn. The local copies get updated, but the svn commit reports exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform a delete directly against your svn repository, rather than as a local change which is then committed.

```
svn rm -m 'remove .svn directory' http://server.name/repo/path/to/.svn
```